# What timeseries database to select for large number of records?

Tags: cassandra, time-series, database-performance

I got into scenario where I have about 100,000 input records per seconds to store. The nature of records is timeseries data.

I need to run both aggregation, other analytics and also some machine learning algorithms over the data continuously. Performance is here the factor as I look for near real-time results.

What would you recommend as database engine?

Comment: Do you want to run analytics against DB? Did you think about writing everything into Kafka, and then run analytics using Spark Streaming/Flink, in addition to writing data into DB

Comment: Hm, that is also possible scenario, let me think about it I will answer.

Comment: This is design for trading system, so even Kafka is the best broker system in the wild, it doesn't fit well due to latency stuff. I go with Chronicle Queue. Still you got the point, I can stream the data directly into Spark from the Queue, where also AI would be running even accelerated via GPU subsystems. Thank you Alex for good hint. So only the results will be written into database and not the records.

Comment: It's often makes sense to put raw data into DB, for reprocessing, reporting, or something like, but at least it will be decoupled from from actual logic

Comment: This is something which requires a decision. I can also replay everything from the queue as Chronicle Queue can keep all data on disk remaining forever, but I am not sure if that raw form is ok or not... requires brainstorming. You pointed out this important thing in design: store raw data in db or leave them in queue for replay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can go and implement your own on top of cassandra with an appropriate data model for your usecase. This will maybe get you the best results tailored to your needs.

You could look at KairosDB (https://kairosdb.github.io/) which is a timeseries database on top of apache cassandra and I got 50k writes per second on a medium sized single (but bare metal) node.

It's quite good documented (https://kairosdb.github.io/docs/build/html/CassandraSchema.html) and it has aggregators out of the box (https://kairosdb.github.io/docs/build/html/restapi/QueryMetrics.html).

OpenTSDB was slower in my tests. Influx looks promising but i have no experience myself: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb

Comment: Thanks for pointing KairosDB, I will definitely take a look. I had in mind specificaly Cassandra. There is also timescaleDB which is really beasty postgreSQL extension, but I am only affraid that I can reach at one day (very soon) the limitations and will need more machines as timescaleDB is not scalable at the moment.

Comment: Influx is also in my scope, I use it already for metrics capturing, but it wasn't for high performance purpose and I don't have any benchmark statistics available now.

Comment: https://www.influxdata.com/blog/influxdb-markedly-outperforms-opentsdb-in-time-series-data-metrics-benchmark/ - also look at Akumuli (https://github.com/akumuli/Akumuli)

Comment: Guys, you actually both including Alex put me on the correct road, thx a lot for these hints.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ClickHouse](https://clickhouse.yandex) analytical database. It can accept millions of rows per second. It can scan billions of rows per second on a single computer. It scales horizontally to multiple nodes. It fits time series workloads.

If you still need time series database, then try [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/blob/master/README.md). It is built on ClickHouse ideas, so it is fast and resource-efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I am adding my own solution...

ClickHouse is definitely nice killer. But I am now evaulating for new project open source gpu database OmniSci. Its open source version is limited to single gpu node (up to 16 gpu devices - with oem tesla having 64GB per device you can get 1TB VRAM, of course not that cheap as clickhouse). Its simply SQL database on steroids (JDBC driver exists) with Kafka data source

Omnisci is having also crossdashboarding solution which is licensed already, but you can have real time dashboarding over lets say 20-50 billions of ts records (8-16 gpus) and multidashboard real time analytics without any kind of preaggregation required, etc....

But it will cost money...

If you want going purely open source, my second candidate is NVIDA's RAPIDS framework which implements cuDF (CUDA Dataframe - like Spark data structure), eventually you can use it to keep your data window (append new, delete obsolete), and cuxfilter solution which is similar to OmniSci, but its more framework, but with skilled frontend coder you can achieve something very similar/same as OmniSci.